# Tables overlapping to next page

Tags: tables

I am constructing a report with multiple tables, but these tables keeps floating to the next page even when is small enough to fit under a text on one page. What can i do? Below is the code i am using. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}


\usepackage[USenglish]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{url}             
\usepackage[hyperref,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper,pdftex]{geometry}    
\usepackage{fix-cm}             
\usepackage{fancyhdr, blindtext}     
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,% 
            linkcolor=blue,%
            citecolor=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}     


\usepackage{graphicx} %%For loading graphic files

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[english]{babel}    
\addto\captionsenglish


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
     \hline
     \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Country List} \\
     \hline
     Country Name     or Area Name& ISO ALPHA 2 Code &ISO ALPHA 3 Code&ISO numeric Code\\
     \hline
     Afghanistan   & AF    &AFG&   004\\
     Aland Islands&   AX  & ALA   &248\\
     Albania &AL & ALB&  008\\
     Algeria    &DZ & DZA&  012\\
     American Samoa&   AS  & ASM&016\\
     Andorra& AD  & AND   &020\\
     Angola& AO  & AGO&024\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Are you using the `table` float environment?

Comment: No, can you send it?

Comment: Send what? I don't understand. Can you please edit your question and add a little but *complete* document allowing us to reproduce the problem mentioned?

Comment: Edited with the full usepackages.

Comment: Since you are using a float environment, your table will float. Please see [`this excellent answer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/3954) about floats.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your objective, but it sounds like you may want to use a `longtable` environment, which (a) doesn't "float and (b) can break across pages if necessary. In contrast, a `table` environment will occasionally "float" to the following page, but it'll never break across pages.

Some additional comments about your code, listed in no particular order:

- If you load the `fix-cm` package, it should be loaded at the very start of the document, i.e., *before* the `\documentclass` instruction. However, since your code loads the `lmodern` font family, there's really no point in loading `fix-cm` to begin with.
- Don't load packages multiple times (e.g., `babel`), especially not with incompatible options (e.g., `inputenc`, which is first loaded with the option `ansinew` and later with the option `utf8`).
- Since you use unusually thick lines, it's a good idea to load the `array` package to even out the intersections between vertical and horizontal lines at the edges of the table.

[image]

```
%%\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % not needed since "lmodern" package is used
\documentclass[openany]{book}


\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{url}             
\usepackage[hyperref,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}     
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}     


\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,% 
            linkcolor=blue,%
            citecolor=blue]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ |P{2.7cm}|P{3.2cm}|P{3.2cm}|P{3.2cm}|  }
%% headers and footers
     \hline
     \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Country List} \\
     \hline
     Country Name or Area Name& ISO ALPHA 2 Code &ISO ALPHA 3 Code&ISO numeric Code\\
     \hline
\endfirsthead
     \hline
     \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Country List, continued} \\
     \hline
     Country Name or Area Name& ISO ALPHA 2 Code &ISO ALPHA 3 Code&ISO numeric Code\\
     \hline
\endhead
     \hline
\endfoot
%% body of table follows
     Afghanistan   & AF    &AFG&   004\\
     Aland Islands &   AX  & ALA   &248\\
     Albania       &AL & ALB&  008\\
     Algeria       &DZ & DZA&  012\\
     American Samoa&   AS  & ASM&016\\
     Andorra       & AD  & AND   &020\\
     Angola        & AO  & AGO&024\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

hey friend  use position specified after `\begin{table}` or `\begin{longtable}`.
here it is:

- `H` - it places your table where you put in .tex file on the same page
- `hp!` - it places where you mentioned if there is no space just after text, it tries to place it somewhere else but on the same page.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Notations used in our work}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\begin{tabular}{c p{6.5cm}}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. `H` is not a default float specifier, it is only available if you load the `float` package. With `hp!` the table will be placed where you put it or on a separate page. Finally, as Mico mentions in his answer, `longtable` doesn't float, so float specifiers are pointless.